# How to find FRR, FAR of a biometric system? And how to plot them according to threshold?

Tags: matlab, user-identification

I am working on retinal identification system. I have to calculate false rejection rate and false acceptance rate. And then plot them according to different threshold. Threshold value of  '8' is found to be suitable for my images. The images having value less than 8 are intruder and images with threshold 8 are authenticated. Can anybody help me how to find FAR,FRR and then plot them accordingly in Matlab?

Comment: Your algorithm presents you a score for each test image. From these scores you can calculate how many false acceptances and false rejections you would have had if the threshold were x. FAR should trend down as threshold increases and FRR should trend up. Ideally, both curves should be steep with EER as low as possible. The actual plot should be trivial to generate.

Comment: @lucidMonkey in my case if the person is authenticated then score is exactly '8'. So i have set threshold to be 8. If score == threshold then authenticated else intruder. I am confused about formulas of FAR, FRR. Can you please help me with that

Comment: Is it possible to post the scoring code? Usually the score is represented as a real value and the threshold is a value that is either exceeded or not. In other words, its usually not the case that score can be expected to be an exact number like 8, which makes me think the score that is output in your case is perhaps some other value that is derived from the score or otherwise normalized in some way. If you see that there is a raw score that is somehow modified to be in the range [0, 8], then just use raw score in plot. Also, is it integral values only or real values?